# Assuming that most of the human experience is based on the body's biological makeup, what would someone experience if they were just a soul

Tags: biology, magic

In my story the main character has their soul removed from their body and sealed away for a very long time. Assuming that the soul is just a carrier for someone's memories and personality what would their experience be like if all physical and biological processes were removed?

Obvious things like hunger and tiredness would be gone but I'm curious about what more obscure things would happen such as how would emotions and thoughts function.

Comment: Immanuel Kant, [*Critique of Pure Reason*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critique_of_Pure_Reason), 1781. First English translation by Francis Haywood, 1838. 856 pages in the densest German imaginable. Good luck.

Comment: Name one experience that isn't directly connected to a physical experience. The simple answer is that without a body to create experiences a soul is essentially in a coma. There is nothing to exert forces on including time. Lookup how coma patients react to the passage of time from a coma.

Comment: Considering how emotions are affected by chemicals in the body and even how the bacteria in the gut take our food and generate hormones, I doubt that such a disembodied soul would have any emotions. It would be stuck in the nothingness of "living forever".

Comment: @IT Alex, that's very easy. I'm sure you have some plans and hopes for the future. If so, then you have yourself experienced something (the act of planning, or a feeling of hope) not connected to a physical experience (because the corresponding physical experience did not occur yet). And even better, you will retain these experiences even if the corresponding physical experience never comes to pass at all. A disembodied soul could be able to have such experiences too.

Comment: @ihaveideas Those plans and hopes are physically connected to the chemical and electrical signals in neurons. Without physical signals, there can't be any experiences.

Comment: @Cloudberry, thank you. No, we merely do not know of any other way. To use this ignorance as an argument for impossibility is a form of fallacy.

Comment: @ihaveideas Soul is a philosophical and religious concept. OP asks about experiences that are similar to those in a biological body. They can't exist without a (not necessarily biological) body. If we conjure up the idea of a soul that exists independent of the body, this question becomes entirely opinion-based: the soul can experience whatever the rules of OP's world allow.

Comment: @Clouydberry, thank you. However, the OP does not assume that. Instead, he assumes that most experiences that humans are capable of having are based on biology. This says nothing about experiences available to souls.

Comment: @ihaveideas the act of planning and a feeling of hope are very, very connected to a physical experience. Inherently, irrevocably so. You plan for a physical experience (a movie, dinner, vacation) if you plan for something non-physically based.... you still are planning for physical things (eating beforehand, the physical location, the comfort needed to ignore surroundings). A feeling of hope? What are you hoping for? Betterment? that reminisces of a previous physical experience. Looking to the future is completely flavored by the past physical experiences. you cannot separate the two.

Comment: @IT Alex, thank you. Nope, still not connected to a physical experience. You can see for yourself if you happen to have a holiday lined up: just don't go, since *you have already experienced other holidays in the past*, and see how it compares... ;)

Comment: @ihaveideas did you just seriously just say that its not connected to an experience because its already connected to an experience? bruh.

Answer (score 2):

Decartes thought the Pinial gland acted as the link between the mind and the  immortal soul. This is not quite as random as it sounds - it is enclosed in a membrane and doesn't seem to be taking information anywhere.

Daniel Demmet gave the term [Cartesian theater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_theater) to describe this sort of thinking. If you describe each part of the brain as a straight information processing system, then you wonder what is in overall control, and doing the tactual thinking. So some people imagine a little man in the head receiving all the information from the senses, watching a screen showing the signal from the eyes, listening to the signals from the ears, and so on.

The other conclusion is that the soul is not some invisible and undetectable control centre, or even a real control centre that we haven't found yet, but it is distributed through all the parts that we can see. This is a provable idea, and we may have started gathering evidence for it.

Now let's look at trainable AI. That may not have shown intelligence, even if it can ape the sort of intelligence that fills so much of the web. But the models are written in a way that you can train the models, or apply the models, or backup the data. It is possible to train the models and use them at the same time. This is how our brains work. But AI models are research tools, so they want to be able to run an experiment, and then re-run it with a slight change, and measure the differences.

It is impossible to back up our memories. To do that, we would have to measure all the analogue properties of each cell to capture the state of it. Then we would have to make an identical system to restore it. However, if AI keeps its ability to stop and back up its state, and can approximate arbitrarily to a human brain, then you should have a computing system that can halted, and the full design and operation and all the internal data can be stored.

What would the stored soul feel? I has no clock, it has no data, it does not have the hardware it once had. It will be stuck at the moment it was stopped. A sensible database might store the data with extra parity bits, so it could periodically correct if a single bit was flipped. Higher strategies could correct for cosmic rays, which can provide a dense shower of flipped bits in a smalll volume. But none of these things is actually changing the encoded data.

It is time. A new body is made, similar to the old one, with similar eyes and ears. The new processor is made to the specifications of the old one. The soul data is downloaded. The processor is restarted. What does that feel like?

Ideally, they should feel like they have jumped straight here from the moment they were stopped. In a worst case, they may be in the body of a baby, and have to wait while a new neural system trains itself about them. But a completely new body is worth the wait.

While the soul was stored, there would be no emotions and thoughts. They are in the unchanging data. They are not loaded on any hardware.

If you were not removing the soul, but just putting the whole body in an extended sleep, then there are other possible effects. It might be worth regrowing parts of the body and resetting the telomeres. The mind may be almost still, but it will probably take some exercise. The mind might take on new opinions.

We have no way of proving any of this, but some of the AI stuff may be starting soon.

Answer (score 1):

The traditional answer is that the soul is the will, and the "intellect". In this context, intellect being a person's transcendent understanding. The things they capital K Know.

Also, ambiguity is the domain of the material. Physical things are filled with ambiguity. Even on a chemical level, things constantly mix with each other. But the immaterial is entirely unambiguous. Immaterial things are completely and distinctly themselves, and nothing else.

Memories are sense perception. Not linked to the will, or directly to the intellect, so a disembodied soul doesn't "remember" the way an embodied one does, it simply knows what it knows, and knows all of it equally the whole "time"

Time in quotes, because how long it lasts doesn't actually matter in the least. The soul itself is not temporal, because it is not material. Souls are only effected by time in as much as they are embodied, so a soul that is disembodied for a second, or for 10,000 years won't know much difference, so long as there is some end to it.

They would also want their body back. Pretty much all cultures agree that souls which are disembodied are not particularly thrilled with the experience.

Answer (score 1):

One answer might be found among [ketamine experiences](https://erowid.org/experiences/subs/exp_Ketamine.shtml). It is an anaesthetic, and with a suitable dose, it is possible to experience loss of your senses (that means, also your body) while remaining conscious. The experiences vary wildly, from just resting in eternal peace to indescribably mysterious.

Answer (score 1):

**No Experience**

Emotions and thought come from the body and brain. The soul is has no body so does not experience things. It is like a copy of Pokémon red for the Gameboy Advance.

[image]

All the game data is on there. But you cannot play the game with the cartridge alone. You must plug it into the gameboy.

Souls are the same. They store memories and personality but must be plugged into a newborn baby for these memories and personality to manifest.